# Opening database inside fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm having trouble opening my database inside fragment java file.
I've used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073189/opening-android-sqlite-database-in-fragment) which pretty much similar to my problem, though It's not working

```
public class fragmentBmi extends Fragment {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity()); //DATABASE

    public fragmentBmi() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bmi, container, false);
        TextView bmi = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.BMI);
        if(db.checkDetails()){ // Check if db is empty, if not print on screen bmi,bmr,rmr. if does print message.
            Details d = db.getDetails();
            bmi.setText(String.format("BMI: %.2f", d.getBmi()));
        }
        else{
            bmi.setText(R.string.noneInfo);
        }
        return v;
    }


}
```

error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int,
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory,
>   android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference

I've also tried Context variable, also giving me the same error.
Is there any solution to open database inside fragment java file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error say that your db object is null when you try to use it.

Try to change

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity()); //DATABASE
```

For

```
DatabaseHandler db;
```

And in onCreateView, add this line after View v =...

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the method `getActivity()` whit an instance variable because at that time, the `Activity` has not been created yet and the method returns null. To fix this issue, you have to move this line  `DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());` to `onActivityCreated` method:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DB is initialized in a variable initialization block, which means it's being executed prior to your constructor (more here: [Java - Method executed prior to Default Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688650/java-method-executed-prior-to-default-constructor)). `getActivity()` returns null at this point in a Fragment's lifecycle (more about fragment lifecycle here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

You need to initiate the db after the Fragment itself was initialized.