# How to use database with fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, fragment, android-sqlite

I am using an `Activity` manager tab layout that has three fragments. I call class Db extends `SQLiteHelper` in `TabtOneFragment` but it is not working and shows this error at Line in Db file.

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
```

I'm using `Db db = new Db(getActivity());` to get context but it isn't working either. Any help would be super helpful, Please!

Here is the Db class:

```
package com.example.hismartversearch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Db extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public Db(Context context) {
        super(context, "Db.sqlite", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    public Cursor getdata(String sql) {
        // error at this line below
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        return c;
    }

    public void querydata(String sql) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void delete_table(String table_name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from " + table_name);
    }

    public void delete_row(String tenbang, String tencot, String giatri) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(tenbang, tencot + "=" + giatri, null);
       }
    }
```

Here is TabOneFragment :

```
public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
Db db = new Db(getActivity());
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
 final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(5), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }

// error at line in logcat when I create table. 

 public void LoadDtaWeb() {
      db.querydata("Create table if not exists tbl_mon_app (_ID integer primary key, IDMon integer not null, IDCH integer not null, TenMon text not null, Gia text not null, ImgUrl text not null, ImgLocal text)");
    }
}
//some text hidden to save space display
```

Here is Logcat:

> 12-15 13:15:30.763 29533-29533/com.example.hieul.hismartversearch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.example.hieul.hismartversearch, PID: 29533
>                                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
>                                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>                                                                                               at com.example.hieul.hismartversearch.Db.querydata(Db.java:33)
>                                                                                               at com.example.hieul.hismartversearch.TabOneFragment.LoadDtaWeb(TabOneFragment.java:309)
>                                                                                               at com.example.hieul.hismartversearch.TabOneFragment.onCreateView(TabOneFragment.java:131)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2209)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>                                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:719)
>                                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
>                                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
>                                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:789)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3143)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2594)
>                                                                                               at android.vi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening Android Sqlite Database in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073189/opening-android-sqlite-database-in-fragment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Rectify your **`FRAGMENT`** section.
- Where is DB **`onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)`**.

> **`onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)`** These is where we need to write create table statements. This is
>   called when database is created.

Code

```
public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
public Db db ;

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one_fragment, container, false);
        db = new Db(getActivity());
```

And

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT);
    }
```

Check [**`Android SQLite Database Tutorial`**](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";   

 String CREATE_TABLE_SAMPLE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_XXX_ID + " UNIQUE,"
                + COLUMN_XXX_NAME + "," + COLUMN_XXXX +
                "," + COLUMN_XXXXX + ");";


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SAMPLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
```